# How to select dynamically fields according to some another field in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have **CloudCredential** table in my project. In table I have 4 type (LIBVIRT, AWS,OPENSTACK, AZURE)(enum) and different size of fields for each of them. Table structure look like

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "cloudType": 2,
        "name": "CedricOpenstack",
        "organization": null,
        "organizationId": 1,
        "azureSubscriptionId": null,
        "azureClientId": null,
        "azureClientSecret": null,
        "azureTenantId": null,
        "openStackUser": "xxxx",
        "openStackPassword": "xxx",
        "openStackUrl": "xxx",
        "openStackProject": "xxx",
        "openStackDomain": "default",
        "openStackRegion": "RegionOne",
        "openStackPublicNetwork": "public",
        "openStackImportNetwork": false,
        "awsSecretAccessKey": null,
        "awsAccessKeyId": null,
        "awsDefaultRegion": null,
        "projects": []
    },
```

I have method like this.

```
         [HttpGet]
         public async Task<IActionResult> GetLibvirtCredentials([FromQuery]string 
          projectName)
         {
             var result = await (from project in _context.Projects
                 join cloud in _context.CloudCredentials on project.CloudCredentialId equals 
                 cloud.Id
                 where project.Name == projectName
                 select new
                 {
                     CloudName = cloud.Name,
                     CloudType = cloud.CloudType.ToString("G"),
                     OrganizationName = cloud.Organization.Name,
                     ProjectName = project.Name
                 }).ToListAsync();

             return Ok(result);
         }
```

Issue is I would like to select according to cloud type, if cloud type = 2 (OPENSTACK)
also select fields appropriate for this (openStackUser, openStackProject and etc.)
Is it possible include if statement inside select.

P.S. CloudType is dynamic which is changing according to projectName and I need multiple if logic inside select.

Comment: So you want a row by row condition which fields should be queryed?

Comment: I would change the last query line from `select new { ...... }` to `select project` and use a foreach loop to create the right result.

Comment: @Ackdari so simply according to CloudType select fields which I want

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the query itself, I mean how should lock the SQL-command?? But you can just query all fields like Jeroen suggested and filter the columns in the application.

Comment: @Ackdari to be precise how I can use foreach inside select maybe some example

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov You you want to return different properties on the cloudType? Or do you want to assign other values to, for example, `ProjectName = project.<some property>`. So it's all about which type you return from this method.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I would like assign values if type == 2 only show openstack properties in output

Answer (score 0):

*"how I can use foreach inside select"* you can't. The query will be translated to an SQL-command so everything you do in the query needs to be representable with some SQL-command.

But you can just query the whole projects and afterwards decided which data should be forwarded

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLibvirtCredentials([FromQuery]string 
projectName)
{
    var result = await (from project in _context.Projects
        join cloud in _context.CloudCredentials on project.CloudCredentialId equals 
        cloud.Id
        where project.Name == projectName
        select new
        {
            CloudName = cloud.Name,
            CloudType = cloud.CloudType.ToString("G"),
            OrganizationName = cloud.Organization.Name,
            Project = project
        }).ToListAsync();

    var actualResult = result
        .Select(data => {
            switch (data.CloudType) {
                // deciding on the cloud type which fields should be forwareded
            }
        });

    return Ok(actualResult);
}
```

Comment: The type of argument method IEnumerable cannot be inferred from the usage

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that returns the right data.

You could try something like, but I haven't tested it.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLibvirtCredentials([FromQuery]string projectName)
{
    var result = await (from project in _context.Projects
                        join cloud in _context.CloudCredentials on project.CloudCredentialId equals
                        cloud.Id
                        where project.Name == projectName
                        select SelectData(project)).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

---

```
private object SelectData(TypeOfProject project)
{
    switch (project.CloudType)
    {
        case 1:

            return new
            {
                CloudName = project.Name,
                CloudType = project.CloudType.ToString("G"),
                OrganizationName = project.Organization.Name,
                ProjectName = project.Name,
                OpenStackUser = project.openStackUser,
                OpenStackPassword = project.openStackPassword
            };


        case 2:
            return new
            {
                CloudName = project.Name,
                CloudType = project.CloudType.ToString("G"),
                OrganizationName = project.Organization.Name,
                ProjectName = project.Name,
                AzureSubscriptionId = project.azureSubscriptionId,
                AzureClientId = project.azureClientId
            };


        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I am not in favor of mixing different types. I would create different functions to receive different object types.

Comment: Are you sure that this wont run into problems with translating the query to SQL?

Comment: Like I said, i'm not able to test this. I think the last part won't be translated to SQL. If that would be a problem, he should foreach the results and yield each row.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it throws when i make request - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.-

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov You should debug that. It could be anything which is expected to be non-null.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen maybe I am using join and returning back results from 2 tables and selectdata accepts one class